# Windows 10 can't set a 16:10 (native) resolution for Acer X223W

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, amd-graphics-card

The monitor worked fine until I installed a fresh new x64 Windows 10 Pro (was x32 before).
My graphics card is an ATI Mobility Radeon 4500 HD series, with drivers for Windows 8 x64, the newest ones from AMD's site.
The monitor is an Acer X223W S, with only a single VGA port.
My cable is fine for sure.

The monitor is detected as a Generic Non-PnP monitor, and the desired resolution is not on the list (1600x1000, if I recall correctly).
I tried the CRU to set a resolution but it failed, I also tried different drivers for both the display adapter and the monitor, for the latter I found the original driver, but installing it didn't help. Rebooting doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I ended up here for this problem in March 2020, so maybe someone else will, too.

Go to Settings>Display. Choose your monitor. Click on the Advanced Display Settings link at the bottom. Click on Display Adapter Properties for [your display]. Click on the Monitor tab. Uncheck the "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" box.

This let me select the proper display for my monitor, and it works fine now.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

[UPDATE] Right after I posted this, Win 10 installed an updated driver for my Radeon card. Now the "hide modes" box is grayed out, and I'm back to not being able to choose the correct resolution for my monitor again. *sigh* Back to the ol' drawing board.

Comment: This also works on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

The native resolution of the Acer X223W is 1680x1050.

You shouldn't install Windows 8 drivers for Windows 10. Windows 10 will have it's own drivers that are automatically installed for a system of this age.

First, go in to Control Panel -> Device Manager and find the video adapter under "Display Adapters," right-click and "uninstall device." Choose the option to remove the drivers also. Now, reboot your computer and let Windows reinstall the drivers it wants to install. Finally, check windows updates for any additional updated drivers that Windows might want to install.

If, after all of this, you still can't use the display resolution of 1680x1050, you can try to use an older driver on the computer. It appears this has been a problem recently with this video adapter.  To use an older driver, find the video adapter in control panel again, right-click and choose 'Update Driver.' Choose Browse my computer for driver software, then Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer. Windows will display a list of compatible drivers available on the computer. Choose an older driver, and try it. It has been suggested to use version 8.970.800.9001.

See here: https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/98765-amd-mobility-radeon-hd4500-not-working-after-windows-10-update-2.html

Comment: I tried both these things, but unfortunately none worked. I have the driver in version 8.970.100.9001, it was the closest I could find. My monitor still isn't recognized and there's not an option to select the correct resolution. Thanks though!